# R, python: "initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite" error

Tags: python, r, numpy, rpy2

I'm trying to use R's fitdistr in Python through rpy2:

```
x = MASS.fitdistr(np.asarray(myValues), "beta", start=startParams)
```

But I got this message:

```
Error in optim(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 34, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in optim(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Now,there are no NaNs in my array, but just to double check I ran this:

```
numpy.isfinite(myValues)
```

...which returned `True` on each value of the array.

Any clue as to what is wrong here?

Comment: Guesses can be harder without a minimal amount of information about how what happens before the code line returning the error. For example, how do you get "startParams" ?

Comment: Are you trying to fit a Beta distribution to a data set that contains values that are not *strictly* >0 and <1 (i.e. do you have values equal to 1.0)?  That usually won't work, because the likelihood will be infinite as soon as shape2<1 ...

Comment: Yes, I have some 0.0 and 1.0. I was using 0.5 for both starting parameters. What values should I use instead?